# include parent directory not working

Tags: php, include, parent

So I have a site that uses subfolders for each subpage, however I can't get every directory to work.

the fotter.php is called in correctly, however not the head.php.
What is wrong?

```
php-file:
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
<?php include('../head.php'); ?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('counters.php'); ?>
<?php include('quiz.php'); ?>
<?php include('../goal.php'); ?>
<?php include('../footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: How should we imagine how your directory structure is?

Comment: This looks like a job for **[autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)**

Comment: I would suggest to use absolute paths

Comment: perhaps an older php with safe_mode and restricted include path?

Answer (score 0):

You should include proper path. Try:

```
<?php include('/home/username/public_html/directory/head.php); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `head.php` file has `read` permissions set for the user your webserver is running as (i.e., not you.) Depending on the operating system and web server there are many possibilities but the easiest would be probably to make it readable for all:

- On Windows GUI: right click the file => Properties => Security;
- On OS X: right click => Get Info => Sharing & Permissions;
- On Linux: OS X, BSD, et al. in the command line, `chmod 0644 head.php`;
- If it's on a remote server, your file transfer client should have some kind of interface to view file properties.

Comment: You probably meant `644`, the executable flag isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, 0644 would do just fine.

Comment: It works if I put it in the same folder and include it, so it feels weird that it should be a read permission that prevents it right?

Comment: Not really that weird. Check the permissions on the file in the folder where it **doesn't** work.